# Is it possible to get 'and' operation using switch statment

Tags: c, gcc, switch-statement

As I have learned so far I am able to use `switch` statement and use it as an 'or' operator.  For example:

```
switch(num)
case 1:
case 2:
 printf("One or Two");
```

It works like

```
if(num==1 || num==2)
 printf(""One or two);
```

Is it possible to modify switch statement and use it as AND rather than OR?

Comment: Don't use `switch` as a fancy OR. It's not meant for that.

Comment: Tq @Pubby fro your comment.. I will keep it on mind.. Tq again

Comment: How would `num` be both `1` **and** `2`?

Comment: got it @K-ballo tq now i get it very very tq for your comment you cleared all my confusion

Comment: that would logically be incorrect. Switch statement corresponds to if-elseif-else ladder. Not, `if(a or b)`.

Comment: This is as well-defined and clear as a question gets. There's no requirement that StackOverflow questions be *practical*, so why the close votes?

Comment: Please consider my answer. If you feel it answers the question, you can always move the checkmark :)

Comment: @Potatoswatter Actually, there is: ["You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). But stretching that rule a bit from time to time is okay.

Comment: @DanielFischer I stand corrected… but the question and the answer are pretty short and definite, certainly no harm done.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I agree. The "practical" and "actual problems that you face" parts shouldn't be taken too literally (but shouldn't be overstepped too far either). The "answerable" part should be considered a must, however.

Answer (score 7):

A variable cannot hold two values simultaneously.

num == 1 && num == 2 is always false.

Does the question make sense or am I missing the point?

Comment: No, the question does not make sense

Answer (score 3):

[De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) is usually the key to converting between OR and AND. As a C expression, it is

```
!( A || B ) == ( !A && !B )
```

A `switch` statement may have a `default` case, taken when none of the other conditions are satisfied. If it is the only alternative to the OR case you already gave, then by virtue of being the opposite of an OR, it is automatically an AND case by De Morgan.

```
switch(num) {
case 1:
case 2:
    printf("One or Two\n");
    break;
default:
    printf("Not one AND not two\n");
    break;
}
```

As already mentioned, this is the only way to make AND make sense, since a variable can't be two numbers at once.

Comment: +1 The reference to De Morgan's Law is outstanding.

Comment: @AatishSai If you feel that this is insightful, please click the up arrow. If you feel it provides the best answer, please click the checkmark.